# Max velocity for a body to remain in contact with surface while exhibiting circular motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

**Q. A particle of mass is attached to one end of a sting of length l while the other end is fixed to a point $h$ above the horizontal table. The particle is made to revolve in a circle on the table so as to make $n$ revolutions per second. Find max value of $n$ if the particle is  in contact with the table.**

Now, I resolved $N$ into its components. Then, I equated $N \sin{\theta}$ to $\tfrac{mv^2}{r}$. Now since it is given that the object should never break contact with the surface I used $N$ to be equal to zero (for tangential acceleration to be max). Which means that $\tfrac{mv^{2}}{r}$ is zero.

Does that mean that as soon as object starts moving contact will break?

Note- I have no answer for this question, but I suppose it to not be a trick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting the Tension in the string, which will be responsible for the centripetal acceleration.

The equations will be

$$ T \sin(\theta) = \frac{mv^2}{R} $$

and

$$ N + T\cos(\theta) = mg$$

where $\theta$ is the angle the string makes with the vertical axis. For the string to be taut, the value of R should be $ \sqrt{l^2 - h^2} $ and for the particle to stay on table $N > 0$.

Comment: Will the particle ever leave the table then?

Comment: If it is possible for N to become 0, then Yes, the particle would leave the table.

Comment: Solve the two equations to find N. Then see if there is any value of speed that makes N  equal to zero.

Comment: And from what I gather, N COULD become zero IF velocity that is mv²/r is great enough and since v is depended on no. of revolutions v= 2πr.n/t.

Comment: Correct. If n is large enough, the particle would leave the table.

Comment: N is coming out to be (tan theta*r*g)/(2π)

Comment: But that would mean that the mass does not matter in this question. Is this even possible?

Comment: **Tension** in the string increases as the mass of the object increases (N = 0 when the particle leaves the surface) , since Tension itself is responsible for the centripetal acceleration, it is indeed possible for the speed to be _independent_ of the mass of the particle.